# Gradle task failing on GitLab CI main method not found

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab

I'm in the process of setting up a new GitLab CI pipeline for a project.

As a start, my goal is to create a basic pipeline that builds, tests and analyzes  the project (3 simple stages).

My problem is that, that my second stage (test) depends on a Gradle task that generates a bit of documentation (we generated on the fly documentation based on tests). Said task invokes the main of a utility to generate a simple piece of documentation.

While all tasks work fine when I run them under a Windows host, doing the same on GitLab's CI using an Alpine Linux based image fails with the following error:

```
> Task :compileTestJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test

> Task :generatePermissionsDocument FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generatePermissionsDocument'.

> Process 'command '/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have tried enabling Gradle stacktraces but I did not manage to get any good information out of them. For the most part both my build script and the GitLab CI script look OK (included below for reference):

```
image: adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jdk8u222-b10-alpine

include:
  - project: "devops/ci-templates"
    ref: "master"
    file: "sonar/sonar-gradle.yml"

variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  - apk add --no-cache tzdata
  - cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
  - echo "America/New_York" > /etc/timezone

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - analysis

build:
  stage: build
  script: ./gradlew --build-cache clean assemble -PMARKETING_SKIP_INT_TESTS
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
      - src/main/java/fts/marketing/util/Version.java
  retry: 2
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
    - /^support\/\d+[.]\d+$/
    - tags
  except:
    - api

test:
  stage: test
  script: ./gradlew test -PMARKETING_SKIP_INT_TESTS --stacktrace
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
      - src/main/java/fts/marketing/util/Version.java
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
    - /^support\/\d+[.]\d+$/
    - tags
  except:
    - api
```

Initially I though that the this would be a caching or permission related problem, but I checked both the integrity or the cache produced by the build task as well as the permissions of the generated folder and everything looks fine.

For reference the task I'm trying to invoke is this one:

```
task generatePermissionsDocument(type: JavaExec, group: 'application') {
    description = 'Will generate API Permissions adoc'
    main = 'fts.marketing.tools.GeneratePermissionsDocument'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    //jvmArgs = applicationDefaultJvmArgs
    workingDir = generatedDocumentation
}
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why this is failing and what must be done to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find out the root cases of this. I was doing some conditional setting of the application's default JVM args which apparently was wrong. Said process was including a trailing ',' in the args passed in by Gradle to the JVM.

For some reason this was not well liked when running from a Unix like environment, whereas it was working fine on Windows hosts. I re-worked the conditional part of the arg setting and everything worked like a charm.